# Configuring Delayed Jobs with Capistrano and Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

I am trying to get Capistrano to start/stop Delayed Jobs with a Rails 4 application.  I followed the [instructions here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Rails-3-and-Capistrano), but it says Rails 3.  This is how its configured now:

**deploy.rb:**

```
require 'delayed/recipes'
after "deploy:start", "delayed_job:start" 
after "deploy:stop", "delayed_job:stop" 
after "deploy:restart", "delayed_job:stop","delayed_job:start"
```

When I try to deploy I get the following error after it tries to execute **RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job stop**

```
sh: script/delayed_job: not found
```

Comment: Looks like the delayed/recipes may be outdated?  With rails 4 we have to replace script/delayed_job with bin/delayed_job

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found the workaround (**set :delayed_job_command, "bin/delayed_job"**) and hope this helps someone else!

**deploy.rb:**

```
require 'delayed/recipes'
set :delayed_job_command, "bin/delayed_job"
after "deploy:start", "delayed_job:start"
after "deploy:stop", "delayed_job:stop"
after "deploy:restart", "delayed_job:stop","delayed_job:start"
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer did not work for me either. I did the following

**deploy.rb**

```
def rails_env
  fetch(:rails_env, false) ? "RAILS_ENV=#{fetch(:rails_env)}" : ''
end

execute "cd #{current_path};#{rails_env} bin/delayed_job restart"
```

Answer (score 1):

For me this didn't work.
My production environment consists of ubuntu 12.04, rails 4, rbenv ruby 2, and for deployment capistrano 3. 
After messing around a lot with every applicable solution I've come up with this line in my deploy.rb in the restart task.

**execute :ruby, "/var/www/app/current/bin/delayed_job restart"**

so simple and yet it took me 2 days to come up with it.
At my setup I had to manually put bin/delayed_job in place.

Hope someone else find this helpful.