# delayed_job w/ Rails 4 not running updated code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

I'm having trouble using [collectiveidea/delayed_jobs](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/) to process tasks in Rails 4. Namely, it works, but doesn't seem to want to update code based on recent file updates. This is true on both production and development environments, although I'm focusing on debugging in development first, just to see what might be happening.

I'm on versions delayed_job (4.1.1) and delayed_job_active_record (4.1.0).

If I run a job synchronously (skipping the delayed_jobs worker) things process fine (the following code is what I use to test that):

```
app/config/initializers/delayed_job.rb

Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = !(Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.development?)
```

But with the delayed_jobs table queue / worker running I end up with a significantly older version of my job per outdated code.

I've tried locking the daemons gem at 1.1.9, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/798#issuecomment-96815090) without luck.

```
Gemfile    

gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'daemons', '1.1.9'
```

I could share more code, but I'm not sure it'd do much good. My testing shows just what I've mentioned.

Trouble restarting delayed_job workers is a known issue elsewhere. But my issue seems to be more specifically that, even if I can restart workers, some sort of more general cache seems to be interfering with proper execution. I have also tried restarting application servers in both dev and prod with no luck.

Any similar stories or tips would be greatly helpful!

Comment: Possible sollution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768098/configuring-delayed-jobs-with-capistrano-and-rails-4.

Comment: You have to restart delayed job to update your change.